# Can I Use ROWNUM < SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL in select statement(sqlplus) on a table?

Tags: select, sequence, sqlplus, oracle12c, rownum

I have an emp table
  SQL> select * from emp;

```
 EMPNO ENAME
```

---

```
  5000 JOHN
  5001 ADAM
  5002 MIKE
```

I need help writing a procedure to run "Select EMPNO||ENAME from emp" on one row at a time till the end of the table.
Trying to use the below statement with N as a sequence.nextval. It does not work. Please help me doing resolving this.

```
select EMPNO||ENAME from emp
where rownum < N+1
minus
select EMPNO||ENAME from emp
where rownum < N;
```

Comment: This makes no sense.  the sequence.nextval should never exist in a table row.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: sorry for not being able to explain. sequence.nextval doesnt exist in a table. I am thinking to use the sequence like a variable so that N=1,2,3 and so on. I need to loop "Select EMPNO||ENAME from emp" to run row by row. Please let me know if I am totally wrong about this.

Comment: What do you mean, 'row by row'?  If you want to access each row's data in some manner, then use a for loop cursor.  Google that.

Comment: cursor yes.. I mean doing the select on the first row in the first iteration and the second in the second iteration and so on. Hoping to get an answer. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access each row and do something with it in a loop:

```
declare
tmp as varchar2(500); -- whatever size you need

begin

  for emp_rec in (select * from emp order by empno )
  loop

    -- do something with record data
    tmp  := emp_rec.empno || emp_rec.ename;
    -- etc.

  end loop;
end;
```

Comment: Edited it as below. Still get this error
""    select EMPNO||ENAME from emp;
    *
ERROR at line 9:
ORA-06550: line 9, column 5:
PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement""


declare
tmp varchar2(500);

begin

  for emp_rec in (select * from emp order by empno )
  loop
  
    select EMPNO||ENAME from emp;
    tmp  := emp_rec.empno || emp_rec.ename;
    

  end loop;
end;
/

Comment: remove your select that you added.  reference the emp_rec record attributes.  If you want the string concat, then change the select in the for loop cursor.

Comment: Thank you it worked but i cant see any output. Can you please help me with this-
The o/p of the first row needs to be spooled in a file( which I will be using with mysql --host command on linux). And then I need the o/p of the second row to be overwritten in the same file which i will run again on linux. Can you help me do this till all rows in the table are covered. This is for my college sorry for the trouble!

Comment: FYI. I am trying to pull this data from oracle and use it to create databases in MYSQL.

Comment: SO is not a forum where someone will write a complete working application for you.  Sorry.

Comment: Its not an application, more like a procedure..Thanks though!